# Why doesn't my queue triggered Azure function app scale out?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I've created a queue triggered Azure function app. It runs in the Premium app service plan because I need to use larger VM instances that have increased memory and compute power. The test I'm conducting mirrors real-life use. It starts by placing about 4000 entries in an Azure storage queue and letting the Azure function burn that queue down until all the work is done. It takes about 12 hours to process those 4000 entries.

That is exactly the problem. Functionally, everything works as expected. The function app does not scale out, however, despite having thousands of queue entries and taking many hours to process. I've verified the lack of scale out by using the app service metrics and "splitting" by instance. It only shows one VM. I've configured scale controller logs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2), but the log file doesn't indicate any scale-out or help diagnose why this is not occurring.

I have a "batchsize" set in host.json, so I get a little parallelization on the VM instance. It's not enough, though, and I need to discover why the scale-out behavior I expect is not happening.

I appreciate any guidance on the issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Scale out your functions manually by defining multiple function apps instead of a single function app. In theory this should result in a lot better scaling since you now have many independent apps processing messages in parallel. As you would expect this made for a good performance improvement.

For Complete information check [Scaling Queue Triggered Azure Function](https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/scaling-queue-triggered-azure-functions)s and Also check [Scaling Azure Functions](https://madeofstrings.com/2019/01/09/scaling-azure-functions-to-make-500000-requests-to-weather-com-in-under-3-minutes/).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The solution you suggest, however, seems like a very poor work-around. If I wanted 20 instances, would I need to deploy the same code to 20 different function apps? I can't believe this is what Microsoft has in mind to provide scaling for Azure functions. I'm trying to leverage the event driven scaling features described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling.

Comment: Deploying 20 separate function apps is certainly not the scaling strategy that Microsoft intended or would recommend for Azure functions.